# How to terminate gulp unconditionally from within a task?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to terminate Gulp without any further action:

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('…', function quit (cb) {
        // ... totally terminate gulp here, no cleanup required, drop to OS system prompt.
    }
}
```

I tried `throw new Error('ciao')` and that would quit the `watch` but not the outer `task` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but what works is `process.exit(0);`